# Can I use Counter on a live file?

Tags: python

The following works fine using a closed file, 'loggedData.dat'. If a number is repeated more than 5 times it shows up in the print out of the List. But I want 'loggedData.dat' to be a live file, a file that is constantly being added on to. How do I do that? I tried adding onto 'loggedData.dat' after script was running but got no response. I'm using this python-2.7 script on my Windows 7 computer, which puts 'loggedData.dat' into its Notepad.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
list_of_files=[('loggedData.dat', 'Nothing')]
datalist = [(np.loadtxt(filename), label) for filename, label list_of_files]
while True:
    for data, label in datalist:
        List = [k for (k, v) in Counter(data[:,1]).iteritems() if v>5]
        print List
```

Comment: `np.loadtxt(filename)` reads the entire file into memory before the loop starts. As you want to read the file as it is being appended to, you need to read line-wise and add those lines as they appear to your Counter.

Comment: You're kind of asking the wrong question - it's the file handling that's relevant, not the use of Counter.  Also if you're only using numpy for loadtxt, consider using the built-in csv module instead https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv

Comment: Thanks Dan, I think I understand. I'll also try csv.

Answer (score 0):

Your core problem is being notified, without needing to incessantly poll, when changes have been made to the "live file" you're watching.

A good cross-platform library for that is [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.5.4) -- it does need you to install a bunch of other stuff, but it's worth the effort.

Once notified that the file you care about gets changed, what you need to do depends on your exactly application constraints.

If changes are arbitrary (e.g include deletions of, or edits to, existing lines), you'll pretty much have to re-read the whole file in its new incarnation.

At the other extreme, if the constraints are very strong (e.g, lines are only appended, never modified once you're there), you may be able to optimize that (only relevant for substantially large files) though probably not if you use tools at a high level of abstraction like `np.loadtxt`.

But I won't expand on that since it would be premature optimization, having no idea what you mean by "a live file" in all needed levels of excruciating detail:-).

Comment: I am simply logging temperature readings along with a cnt+. 0 77, 1 78, 2 77, 3 77, 4 77, 5 77, 6 77, 7 76, 8 75. Only the end of the file changes, as more temperatures are logged in. The temperature of 77 above is repeated more than 5 times and it is only the temps that are repeated more than 5 times that I am interested in.

Comment: Sorry Alex, your too fast for me.

Comment: So, in this case, some optimization might be possible if you're willing to use a lower abstraction level.  But: first make it work -- install and use `watchdog` and re-read the whole file each time it's modified.  Don't bother optimizing until you have the base functionality working